# How to set full calendar to a specific start date and end date when it's initialized?

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I would like to set the initial date and end date.
so when I call the function to display the calendar that will show only date between startdate and enddate.

Say for example the user selects a initial  date 11-03-2014 and end date 17-03-2014  so what i went to display is it will display event of 12-03, 13-03,14-03,15-03,16-03.

I tried to call 'gotodate' display function but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

You call 'gotodate' after initializing your calendar, and you move to the desired date.

Apart from that, in `viewDisplay` callback you set the min and max dates, and you disable the 'previews' and 'next' buttons when user reach the edges...

in the following example it allows navigation between today and 5 days in the future

```
viewDisplay: function(view) {
    var today = new Date();
    today = new Date ( today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() );
    var maxDayLimit = new Date( new Date(today).setDate(today.getDate() + 5) );

    if( view.end >= maxDayLimit ) {
        $(".fc-button-next").addClass("fc-state-disabled");
    }
    else{
        $(".fc-button-next").removeClass("fc-state-disabled");
    }

    if( view.start <= today ){
        $(".fc-button-prev").addClass("fc-state-disabled");
    }
    else{
        $(".fc-button-prev").removeClass("fc-state-disabled");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

dynamic date:add this event in calendar function and this is dynamically pass date by function_name(_start_date,_end_date)
and starting from now viewRender Event:

viewRender: function (view) {

```
                   var moment1 = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
                    var current_year = moment(moment1).format('YYYY-MM');
                    var start_year = moment(_start_date).format('YYYY-MM');
                    var end_month = moment(_end_date).format('YYYY-MM');

                    if (current_year >= end_month) {
                        $(".fc-next-button").addClass("fc-state-disabled");
                        bootbox.alert('Your Academic Session is over');
                        //alert('Your Academic Session is over');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".fc-next-button").removeClass("fc-state-disabled");
                    }
                    if (current_year <= start_year) {
                        $(".fc-prev-button").addClass("fc-state-disabled");
                        bootbox.alert('Your Academic Session is over');
                        //alert('Your Academic Session is over');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".fc-prev-button").removeClass("fc-state-disabled");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please explain as to why your response should help OP ... just pasting code might end up in more questions that answering the question at hand.